# How to move one UIView xib to another UIView xib in iOS using UIView animations?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am very new in iOS. In my project I have added two `UIView` xib files, they are "View1" xib file and "View2" xib file and here I have added one button in View1 xib file.

And when I tap on that button I want to move next `UIView` xib file i.e View2 using `UIView` animations (as like how we push one `UIViewController` to another `UIViewcontroller`)

### My code:

```
#import "Test.h"

@implementation Test

@synthesize MainArray;

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {

        [self loadingView];
    }
    return self;
}

-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {

         [self loadingView];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)loadingView{

    UIView * MainView = [[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]loadNibNamed:@"View1" owner:self
                                                                 options:nil]firstObject];
    [self addSubview:MainView];

    MainView.frame = self.bounds;

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(aMethod:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 110.0, 100.0, 30.0);
    [MainView addSubview:button];
}
-(void)aMethod :(id)sender{

    //here when i click i want to move next UIView (i.e VIew2 xib file)
}
```

Comment: use ca key frame animation

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)aMethod :(id)sender{

    //here when i click i want to move next UIView (i.e VIew2 xib file)

    UIView * view2 = [[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]loadNibNamed:@"View2" owner:self
                                                                     options:nil]firstObject];

    [UIView transitionWithView:containerView duration:1
            options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp //change animation here
            animations:^ { 
                [self addSubview:view2]; 
            }
            completion:nil];
}
```

or

```
   -(void)aMethod :(id)sender{

            //here when i click i want to move next UIView (i.e VIew2 xib file)

        UIView * view2 = [[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]loadNibNamed:@"View2" owner:self
                                                                             options:nil]firstObject];

        CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = 1.0;
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //change animation here
        [view2.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
        [self addSubview:view2]; 
    }
```

or

```
[self addSubview:view2];
[view2 setFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 480.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[view2 setFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)]; // move in
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

or

```
[self.view addSubview:view2];
[view2 setFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 480.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
  [view2 setFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)]; // move in
}];
```

Comment: i want to move next UIview xib But it' not moving

Comment: next xib? you mean View2: `UIView * view2 = [[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]loadNibNamed:@"View2" owner:self
                                                                 options:nil]firstObject];`?

Comment: yes View2 is my next Xib but when i tapped on button animation is not happening it just adding

Comment: Did you try my answers? Put them into the method `-(void)aMethod :(id)sender{`

Comment: and here i am adding this Two xib files on storyboard custom UIView

Comment: i am very beginner in ios if you don't mind i will post my sample project file link now please modified that and post that again

Comment: this is my sample project link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9LDPRgGlU1NNlI1eDlRTk11SHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Krish I edited my answer, easier for you. Please try it. I can't take your project now. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95708/discussion-between-krish-and-anhtu).